# Pipe string, file contents, string into SQLite without an intermediate file?

Tags: bash, sqlite, shell, pipe

I've got this shell script which takes a set of INSERT statements and puts a 'BEGIN TRANSACTION' on the start and a 'COMMIT' on the end. There are a *lot* of INSERT statements and so this makes the insertion a lot faster.

The script I've used successfully looks like this:

```
file_name_improved_sql=foo-improved.sql
file_name_original_sql=foo.sql
file_name_sqlite_db=bar.db
path_to_insert_error=/tmp/fooerrors.log
#
echo 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;' | cat - $file_name_original_sql  > $file_name_improved_sql
echo "COMMIT;" >> $file_name_improved_sql
#
cat $file_name_improved_sql | sqlite3 $file_name_sqlite_db 2> $path_to_insert_error
```

I'd like to improve this so that instead of producing the intermediate file `file_name_improved_sql`, the two strings and the contents of the file are piped in directly.

Something like this (except this doesn't work)...

```
export string1="BEGIN TRANSACTION"
export string2="COMMIT"
cat $string1 $file_name_improved_sql $string2 | sqlite3 $file_name_sqlite_db 2> $path_to_insert_error
```

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418829/do-users-get-reputation-points-for-doing-edits).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either group commands and redirect the whole group to pipe to `sqlite3`:

```sh
{
  printf %s\\n 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;'
  cat "$file_name_original_sql"
  printf %s\\n 'COMMIT;'
} | sqlite3 "$file_name_sqlite_db" 2> "$path_to_insert_error"
```

Either use a here-document as input to `sqlite3`:

```sh
sqlite3 "$file_name_sqlite_db" 2> "$path_to_insert_error" <<EOF
BEGIN TRANSACTION
$(cat "$file_name_original_sql")
COMMIT;
EOF
```

Or use `printf` to combine the elements piped to `sqlite3`:

```sh
printf 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;\n%sCOMMIT;\n' "$(cat "$file_name_original_sql")" |
  sqlite3 "$file_name_sqlite_db" 2> "$path_to_insert_error"
```

Or create a function to frame an SQL input stream into a transaction:

```sh
sql_transaction() {
  printf %s\\n 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;'
  cat
  printf %s\\n 'COMMIT;'
}

sql_transaction <"$file_name_original_sql" |
  sqlite3 "$file_name_sqlite_db" 2> "$path_to_insert_error"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.read` command in the `sqlite3` shell takes a filename to read commands from. If that name starts with a pipe character, it's treated as a shell command instead of a filename, and reads from that command's standard output.

So you could do something like

```sh
sqlite3 "$file_name_sqlite_db" ".read '|echo \"BEGIN TRANSACTION;\"; cat \"file_name_original_sql\"; echo \"COMMIT;\"'"
```

Using a heredoc instead helps make the quoting simpler:

```sh
sqlite3 "$file_name_sqlite.db" <<EOF
.read '|echo "BEGIN TRANSACTION;"; cat "$file_name_original.sql"; echo "COMMIT;"'
EOF
```

Comment: The other answer is better for this case, but leaving this one because the read from a pipe trick isn't well known.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Like you I think the @LeaGris works better for my current needs but thanks for your response.